# Goland IDE - Tests Coverage

Tags: go, code-coverage, goland

I'm recently using the Goland IDE and I'm having trouble getting the test code coverage.
In the package, I right-click and click on 'Run with coverage'. The tests are run but I always get as a result: "*coverage: 0.0% of statements in ...*".

Additionally, the coverage window that the IDE opens after run tests is empty:

[image]

If I run test coverage via terminal and export to html, it works fine. Example:

```
$ go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
$ go tool cover -html=coverage.out -o cov.html
```

Is there any known problem with IDE? Any solution?

Comment: Please report the issue on the official issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go as more details are needed to figure out what's happening. For example, the IDE version, how do you run the tests, is the command that GoLand runs the same as the one you run in the command line and so on.

Comment: Do you run your tests with coverage on the IDE?

Comment: @georgeok As I explained above, yes. Running the tests on the terminal works fine. Only with the IDE is that I can not analyze the code coverage